# MVC search box validation and multiple models in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

To make my question easier to understand I attached a screenshot, containing views, model and controller scripts. Please click the link below to view the screenshot.

http://ithighway.co.uk/others/ProblemMVC.gif

Thanks!

Note:To keep things simpler I removed some lines and comments from controller and views.

Answer (score 0):

In your Action method, you are not getting SearchBox model. First you need to get the model in the Action method and then check for **Model.IsValid**, if that condition fails simply return the model to view. That will make sure it will display the errors.

Having said that, this is server side validation. You can also do a [client side validation using JQuery](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript).

Comment: How do I get the searchbox model in action?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to put the `@model MvcBlog.Models.User.SeachBox` declaration at the top of your _SeachBox.cshtml. (which is why you have the red line under `model.txtSearch`)

The partial view needs this declaration to know what type of model it has.

I would also use a Html.TextBoxFor instead of a Html.TextBox for the actual search field. This will strongly bind your ViewModel to your view.

Comment: Actually I am using I am using model MvcBlog.Models.User.ManageCategoriesViewModel and if I use model MvcBlog.Models.User.SeachBox in _SeachBox view, it generates error.

Comment: You are using MvcBlog.Models.User.ManageCategoriesViewModel on your _SearchBox partial view? In your screenshot your aren't. And if you were that would be wrong. It looks like you are using MvcBlog.Models.User.ManageCategoriesViewModel on your Main (Parent) view, which would be right.

Comment: I can't tell for sure by your screenshot, but you have a Parent view and then a Partial view correct? The Parent View should use MvcBlog.Models.User.ManageCategoriesViewModel and the Partial _SearchBox view should use the MvcBlog.Models.User.SearchBox

Comment: As I have already declared MvcBlog.Models.User.ManageCategoriesViewModel in parent view, I get error when I use (at)model MvcBlog.Models.User.SearchBox in partial view.

Comment: You must be constructing your views incorrectly then. That is how it needs to be done. Why don't you show me what you are doing instead of just saying you get an error.